# openCV error :"CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file)", while running on docker

Tags: docker, opencv

```
OpenCV(4.7.0) /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): data/s1/.mpg in function 'icvExtractPattern'


2023-02-19 12:15:52.218975: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1818] UNKNOWN: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/alignments/s1/.align'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

The above error keeps popping up when running the follwoing :

```
def load_data(path: str): 
    path = bytes.decode(path.numpy())
    # file_name = path.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
    # File name splitting for windows
    file_name = path.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0]
    video_path = os.path.join('data','s1',f'{file_name}.mpg')
    alignment_path = os.path.join('data','alignments','s1',f'{file_name}.align')
    frames = load_video(video_path) 
    alignments = load_alignments(alignment_path)
    
    return frames, alignments
```

```
def mappable_function(path:str) ->List[str]:
    result = tf.py_function(load_data, [path], (tf.float32, tf.int64))
    return result
```

```
data = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('./data/s1/*.mpg')
data = data.shuffle(500, reshuffle_each_iteration=False) 
data = data.map(mappable_function)
```

`data.as_numpy_iterator().next()`

Description - I have been following the LipNet tutorial by  [Nicholas](https://github.com/nicknochnack/LipNet). But in the order to CUDA to work in windows 11 I had to run a docker image with all dependencies including opencv.

I used the following DockerFile for opencv to work

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu

WORKDIR /lipnet

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN apt update; apt install -y libgl1

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8888

ENTRYPOINT [ "jupyter", "lab", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--allow-root", "--no-browser"  ]
```

and a simple docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '1.0'
services:
  jupyter-lab: 
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    volumes:
      - ./lipnet:/lipnet
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]
```

While creating a data pipeline I am associating frames from an .mpg file with alignment
I expect the funtion to return my data to wrapped in a `tf.py_function`. as can be seen in `mappable_function`.

for further information see - [LipNet](https://youtu.be/uKyojQjbx4c?t=1924)
[Nicholas](https://github.com/nicknochnack/LipNet).

Comment: did You able to solve this error?